# The PSD order of $GKG^T+I-GKH^T(HKH^T+I)^{-1}HKG^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was looking for an answer to the following PSD order question -

$A(K):=GKG^T+I-GKH^T(HKH^T+I)^{-1}HKG^T$

where all matrices are real & square, $G$ & $H$ are nonsingular, and $K$ is positive semidefinite (PSD).

If $K_2 \succcurlyeq K_1 \succcurlyeq 0$ in PSD order, how can we prove or refute that $A(K_2) \succcurlyeq A(K_1)$?  Thank you!